# Unable to open file more than 30M

Tags: php, file

I have a file of 31M and wanted to open the file to read.
I am unable to open the file.
Work around is to read the file chunk by chunk is there any other option in php?

Comment: Increase how much memory PHP is allowed to consume.

Comment: I think its best practice to read the file in steps, rather than call it a work around.

Comment: When you say open file to read - is this file being uploaded via the web in the first instance?

Comment: @EdHeal No I am not uploading the file, I am reading a file from the system using php. Using open function to read the file.

Answer (score 1):

The best possible option is use

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

in your php function where u r extracting the file

or

```
 change your memory_limit in php.ini file
```

Comment: and also, restart the apache

Comment: The default memory limit given by php is 128M, I am just using 1/4 of it.